# Text data is not properly writing to marklogic database using hadoop connector

Tags: hadoop, marklogic

I am reading a sample CSV data and then using the Hadoop connector API to write to a MarkLogic database as Text. Problem is, only some of the data gets written to the database a random number of times.

For example, say I am storing 10 records, so there should be 10 insertions to the MarkLogic database. What I get is that only a few records are written, multiple times, randomly. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Here is the mapper code:

```java
public static class CSVMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, DocumentURI, Text> {
    static int i = 1;
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         String line = value.toString();      //line contains one line of your csv file.
         System.out.println("line value is - "+line);

           String[] singleData = line.split("\n");
            for(String lineData : singleData)
            {
                String[] fields = lineData.split(",");
                Sample sd = new Sample(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2].trim(), fields[3]);

                String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(sd);
                Text txt = new Text();
                 txt.set(jsonInString);
                //do your processing here
                System.out.println("line Data is    - "+line);
                System.out.println("jsonInString is -  "+jsonInString);
                final DocumentURI outputURI1 = new DocumentURI("HadoopMarklogicNPPES-"+i+".json");
                i++;

                context.write(outputURI1,txt);                      
            }   
    }
}
```

Here is the main method:

```java
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Hadoop Marklogic MarklogicHadoopCSVDataDump");
    job.setJarByClass(MarklogicHadoopCSVDataDump.class);

    // Map related configuration
    job.setMapperClass(CSVMapper.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(DocumentURI.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(ContentOutputFormat.class); 
    ContentInputFormatTest.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/marklogic/sampleData.csv"));
    conf = job.getConfiguration();
    conf.addResource("hadoopMarklogic.xml");        

    try {
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the sample csv data -

```
"Complaint ID "," Product "," Sub-product "," Issue 
"1350210 "," Bank account or service "," Other bank product/service "," Account opening  closing  or management "
"1348006 "," Debt collection "," Other (phone  health club  etc.) "," Improper contact or sharing of info "
"1351347 "," Bank account or service "," Checking account "," Problems caused by my funds being low"
"1347916 "," Debt collection "," Payday loan "," Communication tactics"
"1348296 "," Credit card ","  "," Identity theft / Fraud / Embezzlement"
"1348136 "," Money transfers "," International money transfer "," Money was not available when promised"
```

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using?